# compiling c file that uses jni.h

Tags: java-native-interface

I am having trouble compiling the following program

PPConverter.java:

```
 public class PPConverter {
    private native void convert(String s);
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new PPConverter().convert(args[0]);
    }
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("converter");
    }
}
```

converter.c:

```
 #include <jni.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "PPConverter.h"

 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_PPConverter_convert (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring){
    printf(jstring);
    return;
  }
```

Since I am working on UNIX, I am using the following command to compile the converter.c file:

```
cc -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include  converter.c -o libconverter.so
```

but I am getting the following errors:

```
converter.c: In function âJava_PPConverter_convertâ:
converter.c:5: error: parameter name omitted
converter.c:5: error: parameter name omitted
converter.c:5: error: parameter name omitted
converter.c:6: error: expected expression before âjstringâ
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Did you read the error messages? They tell you exactly what's missing: the names of the parameters in the method signature.

Comment: I think I need to rest. I can't believe I missed that one.

Comment: The function name is strange. Be sure the name is the valid function name.

Comment: @qrrt1: That's just punctuation in the error message.

Answer (score 14):

In case anyone runs into this error, the problem is that the header file created by javah doesn't specify the name of its parameters (it's just a header file not an implementation). But in your implementation, if you just copy/paste the header file without adding the parameter names you'll get the error.

So the code from your header file (the file generated by javah, don't change this file):

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_PPConverter_convert (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);
```

When you copy it (into your file ending in .c or .cpp), needs to have variable names:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_PPConverter_convert (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring mystring){
```

This will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_PPConverter_convert (JNIEnv *jbi, jobject obj, jstring str){
   printf(jstring);
   return;
  }
```

maby u lost something